# Unable to locate element on a Dialog in Android

Tags: android, selenium, android-alertdialog, appium

The app in *Android* has a *signin dialog* which pops up.
I need to test it in *Appium*  ( with Selenium java)
When i click on the signin button it will open the dialog but *selenium* commands are not able to locate the textboxes where I need to enter *email* and *password*.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("login_sign_in_button")).click(); // works fine
driver.findElement(By.id("email_address")).sendKeys("abc@xxx.com");// unable to locate the element**
```

Comment: What is the error exactly? Like stacktrace?

Comment: Selenium gives me this error :"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)"

Comment: Can you get the `html` and provide that?

Comment: > info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[INSTANCE=0, RESOURCE_ID=com.abc.abc/email_address]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Using: UiSelector[DESCRIPTION=email_address, INSTANCE=0]
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Failed to locate element. Clearing Accessibility cache and retrying.
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Finding email_address using ID with the contextId:  multiple: false
> info: [debug] [BOOTSTRAP] [debug] Returning result: {"value":"No element found","status":7}

Comment: you mean the xml of the dialog?

Answer (score 1):

You probably need add some waiting before the dialog appears. Please try the following code

```
WebDriverWait driverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
driverWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.Id("email_address")));
```

before

```
driver.findElement(By.id("email_address")).sendKeys("abc@xxx.com");
```